# Why is this empty component still being rendered

Tags: javascript, react-native

I built a resolve screen that checks async storage for a key and if that key is true it navigates you to one screen or another. It renders the Request Location Modal for 1 second and then it disappears and just shows a white screen which is the null component. Why is it only showing the component for one second?

```
import { Component } from 'react';
import { concessionTypes } from '@white-shell/global/globalParameters';
import LocalCache from '../../helpers/localCache';


class ResolveRequestLocationScreen extends Component {
  async componentDidMount() {
    const { navigation } = this.props;
    const wasRequestLocationShown = await LocalCache.getWasRequestLocationShown() || null;

    if (wasRequestLocationShown) {
      return navigation.navigate('ConcessionDashboard', {
        concessionType: concessionTypes.food,
      });
    }
    return navigation.navigate('RequestLocationModal');
  }

  render() {
    return null;
  }
}

export default ResolveRequestLocationScreen;
```

Comment: Returning `null` in `render()` doesn't mean `componentdidMount()` doesn't get called. Check the Component Lifecycle documentation of React